# Flask: Python List is displaying values in HTML file with quote marks and round brackets

Tags: python, html, flask, web, jinja2

I have the below function which returns a list

```
def get_entered_datalist(firstname, lastname):
    if firstname and lastname:
        curr = db.session.execute(entered_data, {'firstname': firstname, 'lastname': lastname})
        list_name = list() #this is a list contstructor statement so have () brackets, usually when declaring list we use [] brackets
        for name in curr:
            list_name.append(name)
        return list_name
    else:
        return False
```

It is being called this way

```
entered_names = get_entered_datalist(session['v_firstname'], session['v_lastname'])
```

and passed to the html file this way

```
return render_template('monthlybudget.html', title='Enter Monthly Budget Data', form=form, entereddata=entered_names)
```

The display code in HTML file is as below

```
{% if entereddata %}
    {% for x in entereddata %}
    <p>{{ x }} </p>
    {% endfor %}
    {% else %}
    <p>No data found</p>
    {% endif %}
```

but it is being displayed with round brackets and quote marks as below
[image: display shows list with round brackets and quote marks]

The query getting the values from database is as below

```
select concat([First Name], ' ', [Last Name] ) as name from [dbo].[EAMonthlyBudget]
            where [Report to First Name]= :firstname and [Report to Last Name] = :lastname
            and [budget month] = datename(month,getdate()) and [budget year] = year(getdate());
```

I added a print statement in my python code to check what gets returned by the function and that is as below (shows with the brackets and quote marks)

```
 [12/Aug/2022 15:29:44] "GET /static/images/nu_logo2.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
[('Janak Shah',), ('Julie Wang',)]
-
```

How do I display the data without the brackets and quote marks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your curr variable contains tuples. try this code:

```
for name in curr:
    list_name.append(name[0])
```

I think you need to check of index out for range error.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, it did work. Thanks. Can you please explain what this code does?

Comment: It returns the first item in the tuple

Comment: Thanks. But if I make it 'list_name.append(name[1])', then it gives an error saying 'Tuple Index out of range'. So there is no second item to this tuple?

Comment: No, the tuple contains only one item in your case.  ('Janak Shah',) is a tuple with on element.